# What was the first movie to be re-released with additional scenes?

Tags: first-appearance

*Avengers: Endgame* is being re-released in cinemas, with the additional of a deleted scene and a couple of newly-filmed scenes. There have been plenty of jokes on social media about it being "the first movie to have DLC", which obviously isn't true - plenty of other films have had extra footage inserted for re-release or home viewing (certainly, it's unusual for this to happen just two months after the original release).

So this got me wondering: **what was the first movie to receive a theatrical re-release containing footage that wasn't in the original release?** The earliest I know of was the 1997 Special Edition of *Star Wars: Episode IV*, but I'm sure there must be an earlier one.

Comment: An earlier example is 1969's [The Wild Bunch](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065214/) of which the director's cut was [re-released](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2011/apr/07/rise-of-the-directors-cut) in 1974 "to a sold-out Los Angeles cinema, with Peckinpah in the audience."

Comment: Wikipedia says it's Chaplin [1940s], but Peckinpah brought it to recognition - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director%27s_cut

Comment: Close Encounters of the Third Kind (1977) had a special edition released in 1980, and was also re-released in 2017.  But the above comments indicate it was not the first.